# Как сделать, чтобы CKeditor не удалял тег <script>?

Tags: ckeditor

Как сделать, чтобы CKeditor не удалял тег ?

Comment: Версию редактора озвучьте пожалуйста.

Comment: @lampa, да хрен знает, вчера с сайта последнюю скачал.. А, вот CKEditor 4.2 (revision f74e558)

Comment: @Dazar код вставляете через кнопку "источник"?

Comment: @lampa, да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // разрешить теги <style>
    CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<(style)[^>]*>.*<\/style>/ig);
    // разрешить теги <script>
    CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<(script)[^>]*>.*<\/script>/ig);
    // разрешить php-код
    CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g);
    // разрешить любой код: <!--dev-->код писать вот тут<!--/dev-->
    CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<!--dev-->[\s\S]*<!--\/dev-->/g);
</script>
```

Comment: а куда этот код вставлять? в config.js?

Answer (score 2):

Можно проще:

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<script[\s\S]*?script>/g ); /* script tags */
config.allowedContent = true; /* all tags */
```

Comment: @Dazar мой код в конфиг, код @VenZell можно на страницу подключения плагина.

Comment: @lampa, использовал ваш код, всё работает, спасибо, очень выручили